# The ratio of WHAT type of independent random variables is normal?

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution, ratio

I know that the ratio of two independent normal random variables is a Cauchy random variable.

The ratio of WHAT type of independent random variables is normal?

Comment: If $X\sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ and $Y=c$ a.s. ($c\ne 0$) then $\frac XY\sim N\left(\frac\mu c, \frac{\sigma^2}{c^2}\right)$.

Comment: @Math1000 Sure. What about $X,Y$ i.i.d.?

Comment: That wasn't stated in the problem, and I don't know if there is such a thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll address the case $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d. (otherwise it's trivial).

Then we can't have $Z=X/Y$ s.t. $E(|Z|)<\infty$ and $p_Z(0)>0$. Suppose otherwise: $$E(|Z|)=E(|X|)E\big(\frac 1 {|Y|}\big)<\infty$$ which implies that $p_Y(0)=0$. On the other hand: $$0<p_{Z}(0)=\int|y|p_X(0)p_Y(y)dy=0$$
Contradiction.

Comment: What do you mean by $p_Z(0) > 0$, $p_X(0) = 0$, etc?

Comment: $p_X$ is pdf of $X$. A slightly more careful treatment needed if densities don't exist but the contradiction is the same - around behavior at 0.

Comment: I see. If for example $X\sim\operatorname{Exp}(\lambda)$ and $Y\sim\operatorname{\mu}$ are independent then $Z=\frac XY$ has density $f_Z(z) = \frac{\rho}{(1+\rho z)^2}\mathsf 1_{(0,\infty)}$ (where $\rho  = \frac\lambda\mu$, and $\lim_{z\to0^+} f_Z(z) = \rho>0$, whereas $\mathbb E[Z]=\infty$. A bit off-topic, but very interesting.

Comment: Sorry, I meant $Y\sim\operatorname{Exp}(\mu)$.